# MultiBlocProvider throws an error when I try to use 2 blocs

Tags: flutter, bloc, provider

I was using this setup with BlocProvider without any issues, but now i'm creating a page where i need to access 2 different Blocs, as the changes there need to go to 2 different endpoints.
Worst case scenario i'll create 1 bloc that calls the 2 endpoints but this doesn't really sound great tbh.
This is what i did. i have a simple button that when pressed leads to the said widget (through a file that i call screen and setup the blocs in)
again, this works fine in the rest of the app where i use simple BlocProviders instead of MultiBlocProviders

```
onPressed: () => Navigator.push(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => IncomeExpenseScreen(title:"Income", property: widget.property, expense: null))),
```

This leads to a screen where i setup the blocs

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MultiBlocProvider(
    providers: [
      BlocProvider<PortfolioBloc>(create: (context) => PortfolioBloc()),
      BlocProvider<IncomeAndExpenseBloc>(create: (context) => IncomeAndExpenseBloc()),
    ],
child: IncomeExpenseWidget(title, property, expense),
);
```

}

This child widget then in it's init call both blocs to initialize them as

```
propertyListBloc = BlocProvider.of<PortfolioBloc>(context);
incomeExpenseBloc = BlocProvider.of<IncomeAndExpenseBloc>(context);
```

But instead of working as expected, i get a red screen and a message on the terminal saying that my context is a dirty girl

```
    ======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown building Builder:
        BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a PortfolioBloc.

        No ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to BlocProvider.of<PortfolioBloc>().

        This can happen if the context you used comes from a widget above the BlocProvider.

        The context used was: IncomeExpenseWidget(dirty, state: _IncomeExpenseWidgetState#39035(lifecycle state: created))
```

Comment: you need to put an await(can be for zero seconds) or schedule a callback using WidgetsBinding before you use the context like that in initState, are you doing so?

Comment: what do you mean? an await inside the init? you can't await inside the init

Comment: sorry, I meant you should have an at-least 0 seconds delay (using`Future.delayed()`), or you can do something like: `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(
        (timeStamp) => context.read<MyBloc>().add(...));`, try it and tell me if it works

Comment: fixed it, no. need for timers, thank you though

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to pass the bloc instance instead of creating new on new route/page.

It will be like  with `BlocProvider.value`

```dart
Navigator.of(context).push(
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (_) => BlocProvider.value(
      value: BlocProvider.of<PortfolioBloc>(context),
      child: YourWidget(),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: but how do you do that with a MultiBlockProvider ?

Comment: try to wrap with another `child: BlocProvider.value(`

Comment: I don't think that's a good solution to be honest

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was that I was routing directly to the widget instead of through the screen. thus the blocs were never being provided to the context...
sorry for wasting your time, I'll have more coffee next time...